# Mapping a virtual serial port to a remote serial port

Tags: serial-port

I'm trying to start a multiplayer match on an old game (runs on Dosbox), which uses serial communication.
So what I need to do is define virtual comports on both computers running the game, and somehow connect those comports (on the same network)

Which application should I use to do that?

Thanks
Nitay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Dosbox has got it covered!

Everything is here:
http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Connectivity

The game supported both IPX networking & modem, in addition to direct serial

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free software that creates a [virtual serial port](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). You can use com2tcp:

[image]

Comment: It seems com2tcp is one of the most undocumented piece of software I've ever encountered. I've been using com0com for ages, but didn't manage to run com2tcp properly